# Is it possible to make one-to-one relationship with EF Code First Fluent API if there is not foreign keys

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two tables, Users and UserSettings.
There're mapped on two classes, User and UserSetting

Both have a UserID column, acts as a PK
Every record in Users table has a record with same UserID in UserSettings table, and vice-versa.
There is no foreign key relationships between this tables.
Is it possible to create property of type UserSetting in User (1-1 relationship) without changing the database structure.
Adding public virtual UserSetting UserSetting {get;set;} into UserClass, and then
this.HasOptional(t => t.UserSetting).WithRequired(); into UserMap fluent mapping class
doesn't help.

Comment: To be honest, I also tried this.HasRequired(t => t.UserSetting).WithRequiredPrincipal();

Comment: In both cases, User.UserSetting returns null